# How can I achieve this grid in bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

What will be the column definition in bootstrap to make this kind of UI?

[image: example]

I am using woocommerce to handle my store and bootstrap4 for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

With the [bootstrap4 grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) which is well documented you can use the example below to achieve a bootstrap version of you example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```